# Javascript window.open() more than once to add item to cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, cart, window.open

```
     $.each(sizeSkuID,function(key,val){
        var sizeSkuSplit= val.split("-");
        var url="http://www.hostname.com/cart/add/?p="+sizeSkuSplit[0]+"&sku="+val;

        window.open(url,"cart");


    });
```

I thought I could add multiple item into cart by executing multiple window.open but the above code loop 2 item but it add only the 2nd item in the cart.

If I emulate by clicking one by one (selecting 1 item) at the time using the above code, the cart will have two item in the end.

So why if it loop two time, the window.open apparently run once and it takes the 2nd url?

Comment: Btw the "cart" is only to keep it refreshing the same window rather than opening two windows.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I used ajax before, but the cart/add/ have redirect url which cause problem with ajax return. Plus I dont need to do anything with the result but just to display whatever has been added to the cart. I doubt if I use ajax it can remember browser cookie, I run two ajax url , and open the cart (http://www.hostname.com/cart), it will just be empty, unlike if I run using window.open which added item will be there

Answer (score 0):

It's because you taget the same window (`cart`).

say:

```
window.open(url,"cart" + key);
```

Comment: It works but it opens two window, if there are 5 item selected , it will be 5 windows. Although it target the same window, if I select one and click, select another one and click, it still can add 2 items in the same window. Any other work around? May be I should try to call recursive function.

Comment: I did, well I created the app on localhost and add item to cart of a live site. What I get from ajax was a redirect error. What matter if that url gets run or not. The redirect url go to http://www.hostname.com/cart, it uses php session to remember. But even I get a redirect error (known in firebug), when I run http://www.hostname.com/cart, its empty so I assume its either the http://www.hostname.com/cart/add/?p="+siz ... didnt get run or it did but php session failed. I must miss something here.